# How to pass multiple data to child component using @Input

Tags: angular

I have a question that if we want to pass multiple data to child component using `@Input` how to achieve that.

If we have component something like this:

```
<ex-comp [exData1]="exampleData1" [exData2]="exampleData2"></ex-comp>
```

How to get the data in the child component. Using two `@Input`s?

1. If so, how does we know which data comes into which `@Input`? **Order matters?**
2. If not, how to achieve that?

Sorry if I miss basic point in this.

Thanks..

Comment: I'd say you could have tried this in your code before asking? ;)

Comment: @AJT_82, I should've tried it before asking. But, I wanted to know all the theoritical things before doing it practically.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can achieve that in your **child component** by this

```
 @Input()exData1;
 @Input()exData2;
```

---

```
<ex-comp [exData1]="exampleData1" [exData2]="exampleData2"></ex-comp>
```

Here `exampleData1` and `exampleData2` are data from your **parent component**
and `exData1` and `exData2` are the input names that you can access into your **child component** by above given code.

Comment: I think I missed very basic thing. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @SaiUnique , I am glad that you found your solutions , :)

Answer (score 1):

You just create public variables with *@Input()* attribute:

```
export class ExampleComponent{

   @Input('exData1') exData1: any;
   @Input('exData2') exData2: any;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.